# How to obtain animations by inserting a new cell in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I would like to add a collectionview cell to a UICollectionView with animation. Unfortunately, I don't see any animations.

This is what I tried

```
let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
```

Scroll to cell first

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row-1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])

// => no animation
```

Select item with animation after inserting

```
self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])
self.collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(newIndexPath, inSection: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)

// => no animation
```

Manually call of didSelectItemAtIndexPath (not very elegant and not a preferred method)

```
self.collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(newIndexPath, inSection: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .Top)
self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: newIndexPath)

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
          UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.alpha = 0.5
    })

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.alpha = 1
    })
}

// => no animation
```

However, when I delete a cell with

```
self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])
```

I do see animations. What am I doing wrong and how would it be possible to display default animations when inserting cells?

N.B. `self.collectionView.allowsSelection = true`